# Resolving deadlock in iOS app

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

So I'm trying to convert a project to ARC.  The first attempt, I just converted everything and I had this problem on one of my views, it just hangs.  I cannot click on any UI element, and nothing is printed to the console, and it doesn't crash.  It just sits there.

So in order to start troubleshooting it, I converted all the simple classes and viewControllers, and then for some of the more complex model classes and UIViewController classes, I set the compiler flag for -fno-objc-arc.  My app runs better, but it still just gets in this state where it hangs.  I've never seen this on it prior to converting to ARC.  I was wondering if anyone else has had this problem and what I can do to troubleshoot it.  Thanks~

Comment: I would press "pause" in the debugger and look at the call stacks for all threads in your app. This can point out why your app is locked up.

Comment: @nielsbot Can you put your comment as an answer so I can close my quesiton.  That was enough for me to fix my problem.  Thanks!

Comment: you might want to update your title to be more like "how to resolve a deadlock in an iOS app" or similar..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would press "pause" in the debugger and look at the call stacks for all threads in your app. This can point out why your app is locked up.